# How to compute CJ by groups faster? (data.table's Cross Join)

Tags: r, performance, group-by, data.table

I need to use a large dataset to compute (many times) a Cross Join by groups, and it's quite slow.
Could you tell me any faster way to do it?

Toy example:

```
set.seed(1)
totletter <- 10
LLL <- LETTERS[1:totletter]
nID <- 100000
neach <- 5
nnn <- rep(1:nID, each=neach)  # In my real problem each is not constant
myDT <- data.table(id=paste0("ID",nnn), group=sample(LLL,nID*neach,replace=T))
```

And now the function I want to make faster. Combining the letter of each group with all possible letters.

```
combi <- myDT[,CJ( unique(group) ,LLL), by=id]
```

In my computer takes 92 seconds for nID=100000 groups.
And around 920 seconds for nID = 1M.  (I need it for 1M).

I know this is related with similar issues. Running any function on many subgroups is slow:

https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3988
https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3739

I just need any trick to do it faster for CJ.

Comment: CJ is internally parallelized. If there are a small number of rows in each group, you may be better off using `setDTthreads(1L)` to eliminate parallelization overhead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think a reasonable question is what are you going to do with this large number of combi. Anyway here are 2 options:

1) Get unique groups by id then perform a cross join (see reference)

```
ug <- myDT[, unique(group), id]
ug[, c(.SD, .(LLL=LLL)), seq_len(ug[, .N])][, (1) := NULL]
```

2) Get unique groups then CJ the indices and extracting row corresponding to those indices

```
ug <- myDT[, unique(group), id]
idx <- CJ(ug[,seq_len(.N)], seq_along(LLL))
ug[idx$V1, c(.SD, .(LLL=LLL[idx$V2]))]
```

timing code:

```
set.seed(1L)
totletter <- 10
LLL <- LETTERS[1:totletter]
nID <- 1e5
neach <- 5
nnn <- rep(1:nID, each=neach)  # In my real problem each is not constant
myDT <- data.table(id=paste0("ID",nnn), group=sample(LLL,nID*neach,replace=T))

mtd0 <- function() myDT[,CJ( unique(group) ,LLL), by=id]

mtd1 <- function() {
    ug <- myDT[, unique(group), id]
    ug[, c(.SD, .(LLL=LLL)), seq_len(ug[, .N])][, (1) := NULL]
}

mtd2 <- function() {
    ug <- myDT[, unique(group), id]
    idx <- CJ(ug[,seq_len(.N)], seq_along(LLL))
    ug[idx$V1, c(.SD, .(LLL=LLL[idx$V2]))]
}    

combi <- mtd0()
setorder(combi, id, V1, LLL)
ans1 <- mtd1()
setorder(ans1, id, V1, LLL)
ans2 <- mtd2()
setorder(ans2, id, V1, LLL)
identical(combi, ans1)
# [1] TRUE
identical(ans1, ans2)
# [1] TRUE

bench::mark(mtd0(), mtd1(), mtd2(), check=FALSE)
```

timing:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 13
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result                   memory                 time     gc              
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>                   <list>                 <list>   <list>          
1 mtd0()        1.14m    1.14m    0.0146    1.84GB    0.583     1    40      1.14m <df[,3] [4,094,950 x 3]> <df[,3] [522,766 x 3]> <bch:tm> <tibble [1 x 3]>
2 mtd1()        1.67s    1.67s    0.600   265.05MB    1.80      1     3      1.67s <df[,3] [4,094,950 x 3]> <df[,3] [1,753 x 3]>   <bch:tm> <tibble [1 x 3]>
3 mtd2()     926.29ms 926.29ms    1.08    257.22MB    1.08      1     1   926.29ms <df[,3] [4,094,950 x 3]> <df[,3] [23,859 x 3]>  <bch:tm> <tibble [1 x 3]>
```

Reference:

Cross join of 2 data.tables: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1717#issuecomment-515002560

---

edit to address OP's comment:

Actually besides the memory usage of OP's method, I think the usage of `by` slows things down, as can be seen from the empirical timings below:

```
set.seed(1L)
totletter <- 10
LLL <- LETTERS[1:totletter]
nID <- 1e5
neach <- 5
nnn <- rep(1:nID, each=neach)  # In my real problem each is not constant
myDT <- data.table(id=paste0("ID",nnn), group=sample(LLL,nID*neach,replace=T))

mtd00 <- function() myDT[,CJ(unique(group), LLL), by=id]
mtd01 <- function() myDT[,CJ(group, LLL, unique=TRUE), by=id]
mtd02 <- function() myDT[, .(group=unique(group)), id][, CJ(group ,LLL), by=id]

mtd1 <- function() {
    ug <- myDT[, unique(group), id]
    ug[, c(.SD, .(LLL=LLL)), seq_len(ug[, .N])][, (1) := NULL]
}

mtd2 <- function() {
    ug <- myDT[, unique(group), id]
    idx <- CJ(ug[,seq_len(.N)], seq_along(LLL))
    ug[idx$V1, c(.SD, .(LLL=LLL[idx$V2]))]
}
```

timings:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 13
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result                   memory                 time     gc              
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>                   <list>                 <list>   <list>          
1 mtd00()       1.16m    1.16m   0.0143     1.84GB    0.588     1    41      1.16m <df[,3] [4,094,950 x 3]> <df[,3] [515,150 x 3]> <bch:tm> <tibble [1 x 3]>
2 mtd01()       1.72m    1.72m   0.00969    1.85GB    0.427     1    44      1.72m <df[,3] [4,094,950 x 3]> <df[,3] [599,409 x 3]> <bch:tm> <tibble [1 x 3]>
3 mtd02()       1.05m    1.05m   0.0159     1.85GB    0.620     1    39      1.05m <df[,3] [4,094,950 x 3]> <df[,3] [528,108 x 3]> <bch:tm> <tibble [1 x 3]>
4 mtd1()        1.45s    1.45s   0.691    265.11MB    1.38      1     2      1.45s <df[,3] [4,094,950 x 3]> <df[,3] [4,130 x 3]>   <bch:tm> <tibble [1 x 3]>
5 mtd2()        1.11s    1.11s   0.900    257.38MB    1.80      1     2      1.11s <df[,3] [4,094,950 x 3]> <df[,3] [467 x 3]>     <bch:tm> <tibble [1 x 3]>
```

Comment: Why are these methods much faster? It's supposed to be similar to what the original CJ is doing, isn't it? Thoug working from a reduced dataset.